# Queries on Curl post- http code 500 error

Tags: php, curl

I am using `curl` post process in php to get the website page info as response. I am using the following code.

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    $_POST = array(
    'ddlBoro' => 'Manhattan',
    'txtHouseNo' => '2395',
    'txtStreet' =>  '1 Ave',
    'RadioStrOrBlk'=> 'Street',
    '__EVENTTARGET'=> '',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT'=> '',
    '_ctl0'=>'_ctl0',
    'SearchButton' => 'Search'
    );
    $url= 'http://xxx/xx/test.aspx';
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$_POST);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    echo("Results: <br>".$response);
    echo "<pre>info";print_r($info);echo "</pre>";
```

but i always getting `http code 500` as curl info error.Can any one clarify this?

Comment: `500` stands for "internal server error" - this may be a problem on the server's end

Comment: '__EVENTTARGET'=> '',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT'=> '',
after removing this variable i am not getting this http code error.How can i post this input value.Can any one help me?

Comment: You need to ask the person who runs the server. This is a server internal issue that you probably can't influence.